# Meaning of "informazione veicolata da" in this text

Tags: meaning, verbs

I am trying to read this section about [the role of old/new information in word ordering](http://treccani.it/enciclopedia/struttura-dato-nuovo_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/) in Treccani  and I found the following:

> Per es., nella risposta che B dà alla domanda di A nel dialogo seguente:
>
> (1) A: Ma come mai Carlo non c’è?
>
> B: Carlo, l’hanno fermato i carabinieri. [ø] Arriverà dopo
>
> l’informazione veicolata da *Carlo* è *data*; è infatti già presente nella domanda di A e presumibilmente anche nell’enciclopedia dei due interlocutori. Per le stesse ragioni, può dirsi *nuova* l’informazione espressa dai predicati delle due frasi che compongono la risposta di B (*hanno fermato i carabinieri* e *arriverà dopo*).

I translated "l'informazione veicolata da Carlo è data" as "the information transmitted by Carlo is given/old". But that sentence seems confusing to me. What information is transmitted by Carlo? He does not even participate in this dialogue, but rather is the subject of it. If he called B to tell that he's been stopped by the police, that is the new information, not the old. The old information is that Carlo is not there and that is simply noticed by his absence. I would expect to read something like "l'assenza di Carlo è una data informazione" instead.

I am not sure if this is a question about the expression "veicolare informazione" in Italian or just text comprehension.

Comment: Just read it as «l'informazione veicolata dalla parola “Carlo”». (You may notice that in the original webpage it is in italic.)

Comment: Thanks, @DaG! Aren't quotes usually used to express that meaning?

Comment: Just edited my comment now, sorry. In the original webpage the word is in italic, which is sometimes used in a similar sense than quotes, but I agree that it'd be clearer in quotes.

Comment: @DaG I was indeed wondering who Carlo was!

Comment: Instead of _transmitted by_ I would translate it with _provided by_

Comment: @DaG: Potresti scrivere una risposta?

Comment: @Charo: Se serve sì, ma a me sembra che, una volta chiarito l'equivoco, questa domanda si possa anche chiudere. Che ne pensi, Alan?

Comment: @DaG Sono d'accordo che la domanda può essere chiusa.

Comment: I have closed this question bacause it's based on a misunderstanding (due to the simple fact that the OP hasn't noticed the italics in the word "Carlo") which has been already clarified.